# Dataframe slicing from nearest value that is not date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple dataframe as follow

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,10,20,20,30], "B": [40,40,50,50,60]})
```

I am wondering if i want to get return rows which value is the nearest to the given value.  For example, if I want the return rows that values on A is the nearest to 12, then the results should be

```
A    B
10   40
10   40
```

I saw several post solve this problem but those are applied to date.  May i have your suggestions how to solve this with numeric value?

Comment: If your data is date, you should provide date data as well. Otherwise, people may give unexpected answers, which may not solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try of using [pd.subtract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html) followed by [pd.nsmallest](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nsmallest.html)

```
Value = 10
NoRows = 2
df.loc[df.A.subtract(Value).nsmallest(NoRows).index]
```

Out:

```
    A   B
0   10  40
1   10  40
```